# Updating 2 rows in SQL database with one query string "UPDATE"

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I need to figure out how to update the two rows in my database but cnt get my query string correct..

Here is the code that I am using. If you could provide me with a query string that would be great..

```
string birdnametextupdate = birdsnametext.Text;
string birdnamedetailsupdate = birdnamedetails.Text;

int row = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["PhotoID"]);

string query = "UPDATE Photos Set PhotoName = @PhotoNewName Set Deatils = @DetailsNew WHERE PhotoID = @PhotoID";

SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);

//create parameterised object
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhotoNewName", birdnametextupdate);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DetailsNew", birdnamedetailsupdate);

myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhotoID", row);

myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: So what exactly is wrong, is it the connection to the database? because your query looks fine.

Comment: What are the 2 rows you are trying to `UPDATE`?  From your code above, it appears you are trying to do only onequery

Comment: The query is wrong. The second `Set` should be not there. Also you have a typo in `Deatils`. Did you mean 2 **columns** instead of **rows**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 string query = "UPDATE Photos Set PhotoName = '@PhotoNewName' ,Details  = '@DetailsNew' WHERE PhotoID = '@PhotoID'";
```

I saw error in your query, do not duplicate set. just use comma instead

Comment: Your suggestion code isn't recommended and not safe at all. The reason why you have to use parameters is to sanitize the arguments.

Comment: I got it working it was the "," separating.. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
int photoId = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["PhotoID"]);
string query = "UPDATE Photos SET PhotoName = @PhotoNewName, Details = @DetailsNew WHERE PhotoID = @PhotoID";

using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PhotoNewName").Value = birdsnametext.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DetailsNew").Value = birdnamedetails.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PhotoID").Value = photoId;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The Sql syntax is:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx

A simple example is:

```
UPDATE <tableName>
SET
    <Column1> = <newColumn1Value>
   ,<Column2> = <newColumn2Value>
WHERE <condition>
```